What do the star and checkmark symbols on software in the pre-installed App Center mean?
Having just installed a new copy of Ubuntu a few days ago, I opened the "App Center" software that came pre-installed with Ubuntu.  Looking at the software available, I noticed some of them have a small orange circle with smooth edges and a star inside the circle.  Some of the software has that symbol near the name of the software.  Others have a small green circle with pointy edges, and inside the green circles are check marks.  And other software in a third category has none of these symbols.

So I'm just wondering what do these symbols mean? I assumed they were indications of some type of verification software could get that would indicate to Ubuntu users it was safe or safer to use than other software, but I don't really know.
Hovering over the symbols with the mouse cursor doesn't seem to yield any sort of explanation from the system, though I tried this.
I also asked an artificial intelligence for information about these, but did not feel comfortable accepting the answers it gave because the sources provided by the AI did not look particularly reliable.
Does anyone know for sure what these symbols mean?
Edit:  Found system specs for my Ubuntu machine.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, 64 bit, Gnome Version 46, Windowing System X11, Kernel version Linux 6.8.0-38-generic.

What is the version of Ubuntu being used? The answer could very. Please edit the question and add the version info, not in comments.

This is the rare case where a screenshot could really help.

@David DE   I don't know how to check what Ubuntu version I'm using because I'm new to this OS... just downloaded it and installed it a few days ago.  But I downloaded and installed the version you get at the following link by clicking the green button:  https://ubuntu.com/desktop?_gl=11l12woc_gcl_au*NjQ4MTQwNjE5LjE3MjEyNTk1Mjc.   Since there's a YouTube video next to it suggesting it's 24.04 LTS, I am assuming that's what I have, but I don't really know.

The version is in the name of the ISO .

@David DE   I think I found the system specs.  It says, among other things, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, 64 bit, Gnome Version 46, Windowing System X11, Kernel version Linux 6.8.0-38-generic.

Bottom of the question

@Organic Marble   Okay here's an image of what I'm looking at. I uploaded the image to flickr.  I made red arrows in the image that point to the green and orange circles I was referring to in my original question.    https://flic.kr/p/2q5r5iY

I added it for you. In future, add it to your question using the little image icon above the text box.

While the App Centre is a bit unhelpful in this, the Snap Store website also has the same icons, but with tooltips. Taking the examples from the question:

Steam - Canonical is a "Verified account":


Discord - Snapcrafters is a "Star developer":



This was reported and fixed back in Feb 2023, but much of the code seems to have been re-written since, and the fixes lost.
For developers, these two seem to be the only special classes.

So Canonical with the green checkmark means Canonical certifies the software is verified/authentic.  Okay.  What about the star in the orange circle? I mean, "Star developer" --- what does that mean?

See the link: "The idea behind this feature is to celebrate and highlight active, responsible participants of the community. Star Developers are representatives that others can trust to deliver high quality snaps and support others in the forum."
